Office Scripts - Excel: format part of strings
I have excel cells that contain strings. I would like to format (e.g. bold) only part of the string using Office Scripts.
For example, a cell of which the content is like this:
Cell content
I want to change its format to this:
Cell content
Copilot gave the following answer but it won't work because setBold only accepts one argument.
cellRange.getFormat().getFont().setBold(true, { start: 0, end: 3 })


I think this has been asked before and it was discovered that it’s not yet possible in office scripts. Perform a recording to confirm.

Microsoft documentation:

ExcelScript.RangeFont interface


I'm on the Office Script team.
There is not currently an API to support this scenario in Office Scripts as of 2024-08-01.
This seems like a useful scenario to support however! :)
